# Can WPF control easily ported to Windows 8 RT platform?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, windows-8

Since VS cannot work on windows RT I guess some gurus will make one, but for own purpose, is it possible to use or easily port wpf code editor control like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor on windows RT ? What would be the steps ?

Answer (score 1):

Vs2012 allows you to remotely debug onto an RT device. So there's no real need.

See http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/10/26/remote-debugging-windows-store-apps-on-surface-arm-devices.aspx